# Initialising SAS Multidimensional array from another dataset

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, sas

I have a data set `types` which is `100 rows x 61 columns`. The first column indicates the `Type_ID` and the remaining 60 columns relate to time periods.

In another data step `calculate`; I want to create a multi-dimensional array  `timeType{100,60}` that is initialized by the 100 rows and 60 columns of data from `types`.

All the SAS documentation I've read so far, initialises multi-dimensional arrays using explicit column references, and the array then forces the columns to fit the array dimensions.

How can I effectively read-in a dataset into the array?

Comment: All 60 columns are numeric?  Might be good to post sample data with, say, 3 rows and 5 columns.

Comment: Why do you want to load all 6,000 variables into an array?  Is this a temporary array or are you going to store it on a dataset?  What's the use case here?  There may be an alternative way to handle things than a two dimensional array, which is not a very common data structure nor a very easily used one in SAS.

Comment: I'm applying 60 discount rates across a number of amounts. I currently have 4 different discount types, and I coded up a solution for that but I couldn't work out how to generalize it for _n_ different discount types, and _m_ different discount periods.

I have upwards of 100K amounts, and the present value calculations need to be done multiple times for different components of the transaction (I'm using self generating code to handle the various transaction components) but the core piece of calculating present values I thought do in memory would be more efficient.

Comment: Consider hash tables. Also consider adding those details to your question, and adding some sample data people can play with (the input data you have, and output you want)

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to Quentin.  I used the Dorfman made famous construct `do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(end)` for the reading loop.

```
data types;
  do type_id = 1 to 100;
    array x x1-x60;
    do over x; global_counter+1; x = global_counter; end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data calculate(keep=testid result) typesread_check(keep=x1-x60);

  array matrix(100,60) _temporary_;

  * load matrix;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (end);
    set types end=end;
    array x x1-x60;    * this array is composed of variables that are filled by the SET operation;
    do _i_ = 1 to dim(x);
      matrix(_n_,_i_) = x(_i_);
    end;
  end;

  * unload matrix to check load with COMPARE;
  * can be commented out / removed after confidence established;
  do _n_ = 1 to 100;
    do _i_ = 1 to 60;
      x(_i_) = matrix(_n_,_i_);
    end;
    output typesread_check;
  end;

  * perform computations that output;
  testid = 1;
  result = sum(of matrix(*));

  output calculate;
run;

* output is zero rows of differences. That means the matrix was populated correctly;
proc compare noprint data=types(drop=type_id) compare=typesread_check out=diff outnoequal;
run;
```

If you want to keep the calculation results along type data remove the `_temporary_` option.  `keep (testid result matrix:)` to get output that has 6,000 additional columns corresponding to matrix(100,60)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not big on arrays, and below won't win any style points, but it's a start.

Basic approach is to use a DoW-loop to read all of the data into the two-dimensional array.

```
data have;
  do TypeID=1 to 5;
    p1=10*TypeID;
    p2=100*TypeID;
    p3=1000*TypeID;
    output;
  end;
run;

data _null_;
  *DOW loop to read data into array;
  do until (last);
    set have end=last;

    array timeType(5,3) _temporary_;
    array p{*} p:;

    row++1;
    do col=1 to dim(p);
      timeType{row,col}=p{col};
    end;
  end;

  *PUT the values of the array to the log, for checking;
  do i=1 to dim1(timeType);
    do j=1 to dim2(timeType);
      put timeType{i,j}=;
    end;
  end;

  drop row col i j;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a HASH object instead.  First either transpose your rates into a normal dataset instead of "matrix". Or just create it originally that way.

```
data rates;
  do type=1 to 3 ;
    do time=1 to 3 ;
      input rate @@ ;
      output;
    end;
  end;
cards;
.1 .2 .3  .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9
;
```

Now let's make some example data. I included one record that will not match any record in the rate table.

```
data have ;
  input type time amount expected;
cards;
1 2 100 20
2 3 100 60
4 5 100  .
;
```

Now load the rates into a HASH object and use the .FIND() method to locate the rate for the current TYPE and TIME combination.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  if _N_ = 1 then do;
   declare hash h(dataset:"rates");
   rc = h.defineKey('type','time');
   rc = h.defineData('rate');
   rc = h.defineDone();
   call missing(rate);
   drop rc;
  end;
  if (0=h.find()) then payment=amount*rate;
run;
```

Results.

```
Obs    type    time    amount    expected    payment    rate

 1       1       2       100        20          20       0.2
 2       2       3       100        60          60       0.6
 3       4       5       100         .           .        .
```